# Scope while in nested map

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and would like to have access to route. I need access to both stop (which I do have) and route, but it seems like the scope closes within the mapping of busStops. Is there a way where I can get access to route?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
  busRoutes.map((route) => {
    busStops.map((stop) => {
      // would like access to current route here
    })
  })
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything specific to do with ES6. Every function in JS is a closures, every function has access to variables exiting in an outer (lexical) scope.

Answer (score 0):

You **do have** access to outer scoped variables, so just use them.

For example:

```js
alert([1, 2, 3].map(i => {
  return ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(c => c + i)
}))
```

Comment: Hi Amit,

Thanks for the answer, but when I open up the debugger, I get the following: "Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined". I can get access to stop - which returns an object, but not route. I do have access to other variables outside of the map (such as the busRoutes variable, but would like to have access to that specific route while it's iterating). Thanks.

Comment: I'd check for spelling mistakes. Anyway, regarding what you've asked, you can access variables from the outer scope as my answer shows. If it's not a spelling issue, try to reproduce your bug in a minimal environment and share the details on your question

Comment: You can simplify that to: `alert([1, 2, 3].map(i => ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(c => c + i))`